# Share All Resharper code formatting/inspection options

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, code-analysis

As denoted in [This Article](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/09/save-or-save-to-in-resharper-options/) ReSharper's *.sln.DotSettings* file contains only those settings which values changed from default ones. Is there a way to store *all* the code editting and code inspection settings in a team-shared layer, regardless of the value being changed or default?

The only way to do this I see is changing each and every value and switching it back (so all of them end up in *.sln.DotSettings* file), however this seems to be quite a time-consuming task.

The problem I'm trying to avoid is as follows:

Suppose a team has 2 developers, say Jessika and John, and they decide that they are OK with Resharper's default to prefix private fields with with an underscore:

```
int _myPrivateField = 1;
```

So they are not changing the "*Instance fields(private)*" setting under "C# Naming Style" section and check in the *.sln.DotSettings* file. 
However, when Jessica checks out the source code on her home laptop it Resharper still suggests using

```
 int myPrivateField = 1;
```

because her computer has its setting changed to have no prefix, saved as "*Save to this computer*". As denoted in Resharper's docs if a "This Computer" layer has a value for a setting, whereas the other layers don't the value will be applied (see the middle green setting in this picture: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/layers3.png

Answer (score 1):

Regrettably, at the moment we can offer no option other than changing options one by one and saving them in the requisite layers. We are aware that this approach is inconvenient, and are in discussions as to how to best handle this.